# pandas data analysis comparing two different rows depending on values in multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
df
   col1  col2  col3
0     1   "A"    10
1     1   "B"    20
2     1   "C"    30
...
n     k   "A"    15
n+1   k   "B"    10
n+2   k   "C"     5
```

I would like to compare the `col3` values across rows with matching `col1` values with specific values of `col2`("A" vs "B" and "A" vs "C").

Let's suppose I generate a resulting data analysis dataframe, it will look like this:

```
da_df
       col1    col2
0    "AvsB"    33.3  #10/30*100
1    "AvsC"    50.0  #10/20*100
...
2k   "AvsB"     150  #15/10*100
2k+1 "AvsC"     300  #15/5*100
```

How can I do it without `for` loops?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html), then loop over the [`combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) of columns:

```
from itertools import combinations

comb = combinations(df['col2'].unique(), r=2)

tmp = df.pivot(index='col1', columns='col2', values='col3')

out = (pd.concat({f'{x}vs{y}': tmp[x].div(tmp[y]).mul(100)
                  for x, y in comb},
                 names=['combination'])
         .reset_index('combination', name='value')
         .sort_index()
      )
```

Output:

```
     combination       value
col1                        
1           AvsB   50.000000
1           AvsC   33.333333
1           BvsC   66.666667
k           AvsB  150.000000
k           AvsC  300.000000
k           BvsC  200.000000
```

##### Restrict to specific combinations

Note that if you're only interested in specific conditions, you can just manually feed those:

```
comb = [('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C')]

tmp = df.pivot(index='col1', columns='col2', values='col3')

out = (pd.concat({f'{x}vs{y}': tmp[x].div(tmp[y]).mul(100) for x,y in comb},
                 names=['combination'])
         .reset_index('combination', name='value')
         .sort_index()
      )
```

Output:

```
     combination       value
col1                        
1           AvsB   50.000000
1           AvsC   33.333333
k           AvsB  150.000000
k           AvsC  300.000000
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to `mozway's` answer. But I think my code is simpler and should be efficient.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Create Col1 by replicating 5 cases 3 times each
col1_values = np.repeat(['Case1', 'Case2', 'Case3', 'Case4', 'Case5'], 3)

# Create Col2 with 3 different observations for each value of Col1
col2_values = np.tile(['A', 'B', 'C'], 5)

# Create Col3 as numeric values
col3_values = np.random.rand(15)*100

# Create the DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': col1_values, 'col2': col2_values, 'col3': col3_values})
df1 = pd.pivot_table(df, values = ['col3'], index = ['col1'], columns = ['col2'], aggfunc= 'mean').reset_index()
df1.columns = df1.columns.map('_'.join).str.strip('|')
df1 = df1.assign(AvsC = lambda x: x['col3_A']/x['col3_C'])
df1 = df1.assign(BvsC = lambda x: x['col3_B']/x['col3_C'])

print(df1)

col1_     col3_A     col3_B     col3_C      AvsC      BvsC
0  Case1  39.101404  28.564307  69.350939  0.563819  0.411881
1  Case2  19.903692  50.989200  94.227183  0.211231  0.541130
2  Case3  14.830127  28.185849  14.900414  0.995283  1.891615
3  Case4  29.918815  36.282592  84.880638  0.352481  0.427454
4  Case5  74.119780  95.239943  99.377965  0.745837  0.958361
```

Comment: Your code is not simpler, it's less generic. You hardcoded the `AvsC`/`BvsC`. Imagine having A/B/C/D/E and needing all combinations, now you'll have to type 10 lines of `assign`. I updated my answer to show how to use only specific combinations.

Comment: Then we will use loop in `assign` function.

Comment: I just don't understand the claim of being *simpler*, I'm using a `pivot`, then the core of my code is essentially `{f'{x}vs{y}': tmp[x]/tmp[y]*100 for x,y in comb}`. There are many ways of doing a loop, here I'm using a dictionary comprehension, but I really don't get how this is really different…

Comment: Why bother about the claim? Let people decide.

Comment: "Why bother about the claim?" Why bother with making the claim to start with? Let people decide.

Comment: @MichaelS. Because he has the habit of doing the same. I just gave him his own medicine. Check this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76745081/how-can-i-sum-columns-in-a-data-frame-for-rows-within-a-range-of-values-that-inc/76745162#76745162

Comment: That seems like an example of a constructive suggestion or, at the very least, a call to justify the answer. Stating that something is "simpler" without backing up *why* that's the case is needless.

Comment: @ragas I have the habit of commenting when there is a **real** thing on efficiency. In the linked case `np.select` would mean computing the mask on each category, which was an important information (there was no *argumentum ad hominem* in my comment and I'm sorry if this offended you). Here you just reused more or less the same logic as mine, then claimed to be simpler and more efficient, which I think is not true. Actually your code runs slower than mine. I'm all in favor of comparing solutions, but please back it up with verifiable facts.